# How to determine whether the database already exists by coding in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Are there any ways to determine whether the database already exists in Apache IoTDB? I want to know a way to use coding to determine the database without connecting one by one, since it is impossible to manually check every server during batch deployment of my scenario. Does anyone know what the solution may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try constructing a similar query statement like `{"sql":"show databases root.**"}` in Apache IoTDB. If you use the cluster mode in IoTDB, then `show cluster` can be used to check the status of database.